# when i use a recyclerView in android studio not respond to onClickListner why?

Tags: java, android

when i use recyclerView or listview with custom layout in my apps ,these not respond with onClicklietner or even setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Please attach the code of what you have tried , mentioned information is not enough  to reproduce and resolve issue

Comment: you can add click listeners to `ItemView` in you `AdapterClass` in your `ViewHolder`